# How can I preload <script type="module"> on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, firefox, preload

I'm in a bit of a pickle - I am attempting to have an essential script and its dependencies preload on my SPA app.

The setup I have is roughly:

```
<head>
...
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="/app.js"
  as="script"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="/dependency.js"
  as="script"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<script src="/app.js" type="module"></script>
...
</body>
```

This works excellently for Safari and Chromium derivatives (as evidenced by the Network developer panel), but not Firefox. I am greeted with the console hint `...Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly.` If `rel="modulepreload"` is used, it works on Chromium and Firefox, but not Safari (this property seems new / not well supported).

Am I missing something? I feel like I'm looking over something very simple, and for the life of me I cannot get it to work on Firefox. Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: `rel="modulepreload"` try adding this on the script tag